# Apatana Studio 3 Shortcut For File Navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

This is driving me nuts....In Aptana 3, what is the shortcut to navigate to a file?? ctrl + O navigates within a file, but how do I quickly open another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to your question is `CTRL+T`

** EDIT **
if you press `CTRL+SHIFT+L` twice you land on the shortcut preferences